# How to reduce Time Complexity to Improve Program Performance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just getting into learning Time and Space Complexities and I was just wondering what can I do to reduce the Time Complexity in this program. I have a very simple example to generate all possible squares on a chessboard.

```
def generate_list():
    generate = []
    for i1 in 'abcdefgh':
        for i2 in range(1,9):
            generate.append([i1,i2])
    return generate
```

As a side question, are there specific tricks/data structures that I could use to reduce the time complexity of a program if I have slow code? Thank you. I am using Atom Text Editor with Python(3.9).

Comment: The time complexity of your function is **not O(n^2)** it's constant time, i.e. O(1)

Comment: You can't reduce the time complexity by that much

Comment: Think of this way. If you have to read a book completely. You have to go through all pages. Sure, you can read a page faster taking less time overall but still you have to go through all pages. This code is no different. It is going to be have the same time complexity regardless of how many optimization you make.

Comment: What the answers fail to address is that your code is already *step optimal*. This is because there are 8\*8 squares in the chess board, so you must do 8\*8 steps. But yes, trick like generators will speed up your code

Comment: @DylanMadisetti generators will not speed up the code because he still has to put whatever was "generated" into a list. I will even wager to say that using extra generators will be slower

Comment: @smac89 has a point. Generators are for memory optimization not for time optimization.